# An exception in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

I need to convert Bitmap image to vector image , this is my code:

```
VectorImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(CamImage);
```

where `CamImage` is Bitmap and I have this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: I don't know the inner exception , can you help me to find it?

Comment: Inspect the `Exception.InnerException` property. Debugger can help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is probably happening because you haven't copied the required unmanaged dlls next to the application exe.

If you downloaded EmguCV via nuget, in the packages folder you'll see a lib and an opencv folder. You have to copy the dlls in the opencv folder next to the application exe.

[Check the documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.), it has a list of possible causes.